# On un-selecting the value of one Select2::widget It remove the filter from all columns

Tags: php, yii2

[image: On unselect District name the state name value is also unselect how to prevent this.]

On unselect District name the state name value is also unselect how to prevent this.

Select2::widget inside grid View For state name and district name

On un-selecting the value of one Select2::widget It remove the filter from all columns

Please Provide the solution

```
  <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
   <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn','header'=>'S.No.','headerOptions' => [
                     'style' => 'color:#3c8dbc'],],
        [ 
            'attribute' => 'state_id',
            'filter' => Select2::widget([
                'name' => 'DistrictSearch[state_id]',
                'value' => isset($_GET['DistrictSearch']['state_id']) ? $_GET['DistrictSearch']['state_id'] :"",
                'data' => dependentFilterDropdown('state',$_GET),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select All','multiple' => true,'onchange' => 'refreshFilter(this.value)'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]),
            'value' => 'state.state_name'
        ],
        [ 
            'attribute' => 'district_name',
            'filter' => Select2::widget([
                'name' => 'DistrictSearch[district_name]',
                'value' => isset($_GET['DistrictSearch']['district_name']) ? $_GET['DistrictSearch']['district_name'] :"",
                'data' => dependentFilterDropdown('district',$_GET),
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select All','multiple' => true,'onchange' => 'refreshFilter(this.value,"d")'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]),
            'value' => 'district_name'
        ],
        Utilities::Phase(),
        Utilities::CreatedAt('index'),    
        Utilities::UpdatedAt('index'), 

    ],
]); ?>
```

```
This function is call after unselect the filter value.

function refreshFilter(value,type){

    if (value == "") {
        window.location.replace("create");process.exit();
    } 
}
```

Comment: why did you add onchange? Are these two fields depends on together? or are they totally independent?

Comment: These two fields depends on together. 
what should i use in place of onchange?